# Django Filter for week_day on DateTime

Tags: django, django-queryset

Im trying to use the filter week_day as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#week-day)

> week_day¶
>
> ```
> For date and datetime fields, a ‘day of the week’ match. Allows chaining additional field lookups.
>
> Takes an integer value representing the day of week from 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday).
> ```

```
entries = Booking.objects.filter(date__week_day__gte=2)
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Unsupported lookup 'week_day' for DateField or join on the field not permitted.
```

How come this does not work? The documentations shows it there..

Comment: It will match if you do: `entries = Booking.objects.filter(date__week_day=2)` But the use of `__gte` is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `week_day__gte` will be available in Django 1.9, but it is not possible in Django 1.8. You linked to the [development docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#week-day), the [1.8 docs are here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#week-day).

Answer (score 2):

There are not so many week days and lookup `week_day__gte`, as mentioned in Alasdair answer, is not available yet.

To solve that problem, you can specify each week day separately:

```
import operator

entries = Booking.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, [Q(date__week_day__gte=weekday) for weekday in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]))
```