# How to order by queryset by Saturday to Sunday in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, sql-order-by, django-queryset

I want to order an attendance queryset by Saturday to Friday.
How can I achieve it?

```
class ReportsTogether(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE,verbose_name=_("Report For User"))
    user_log = models.ManyToManyField(UserTimeInOut,verbose_name=_("User Attendance"))
    user_break = models.ManyToManyField(UserBreak,verbose_name=_("User Break"))
    user_lunch = models.ManyToManyField(UserLunchBreak,verbose_name=_("User Lunch 
    Break"))

    time = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Date"),null=True)
```

Comment: I think this answer will helpp you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461904/django-filter-for-week-day-on-datetime

Comment: This answer shows how to filter by week_day but i want to sort queryset by Saturday to Friday

Answer (score 1):

You can use order_by and week_Day combination on queryset to order it by weekday.

Something like this:

```
qs=Modelname.objects.all().order_by('-time__week_day')
```

This will order result by weekdays in desc order from sat to sunday as day 1
being Sunday and day 7 being Saturday.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
from django.db.models import F
qs = ReportsTogether.objects.annotate(my_week_day=F('time__week_day')%7).order_by('my_week_day')
```

According to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#week-day): "Takes an integer value representing the day of week from 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday).", you just need to get the weekday value and take its modulo of 7